# CDK Step Functions - How to create a loop

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to migrate a Step function that I created with the AWS interface and I encountered an issue with reproducing the following behavior:

Based on a condition, I want my task 2 to either execute task 3 and come back to the task 1 or to end the step function. **My issue is the red path on the image**
[image]
Here is the code I have for now:

```
sfn.Chain.start(OtherTaskWeDoNotCare)
  .next(task1)
  .next(
    new sfn.Choice(this, "task2").when(
      sfn.Condition.booleanEquals("$.isFinished", false),
      task3.next(task1) // This is not working
    )
  );
```

Hope someone can help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally found how to do! 
Here is the code:

```
sfn.Chain.start(OtherTaskWeDoNotCareHere)
  .next(task1)
  .next(
    new sfn.Choice(this, "task2")
    .when(
      sfn.Condition.booleanEquals("$.isFinished", false),
      task3.next(task1)
    )
    .otherwise(new sfn.Succeed(this, "Done"))
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you were able to figure it out!

Here's some additional information regarding iterating through a loop with Step Functions and Lambda: [Iterating a Loop Using Lambda - AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-create-iterate-pattern-section.html)